# bibliography author list truncate to firstauthor et al. if more than author

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, author

This is the relevant part of my modified.bst that determines the author list format:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #3
          #1 + =
          numnames #4
          > and
            { " et~al." * }
            'skip$
          if$
          s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ 't :=
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

When it comes to compilation, it works fine if I have 4, 5 or more authors. Then it compiles to F. Author et al. However, if I have one or two authors in the list, it only prints F. Author. So, no, et al. Following that, neither is the printing name of the second author. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could modify the parts of the code that do simply F. Author if there is only one author, and F. Author et al. if there are multiple authors (more than ONE).
thanks.